# Tag answer-score inconsistency in same user activity page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-badges, tag-score, activity-summary

The new format for User Activity page now shows the "Next tag badge" with the vote score and the answer score for that tag.

In my [user activity page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/8321/babou), I had noted a discrepancy, as the information for the vote score was 18 in the "Next tag badge" information, and 19 in the Tags section of the summary of activities. The vote score was first below 100, then above 100 without any effect.

The answer score was increased by 1 about a day ago, and both numbers were increased, the former to 19 and the latter to 20.

Since no badge was awarded, I concluded that the former value of 19 in the "Next tag badge" information is the one that counts. No big issue. But it might be better to have consistent reporting and the same value on both places.

The tags raising this problem for me is [compilers](/questions/tagged/compilers).

In case my user page evolves, and you need to see the inconsistency, I am keeping a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover over the number to the left of the tag, in the tags section, you will see a tooltip that explains that 19 of the posts are on answers and 1 on a question, totalling 20 posts.

So, there is no discrepancy here.

The total number of posts you have in the tag is 20.

However, to qualify for the tag badge, you need 20 *answers*, of which you are one short.